# Hiding Superfish Dropdown on Specific Menu Item

Tags: routes, navigation

I am working on a Drupal site that has a series of about 2 dozen articles. I have a page called "News" which lists the title/teaser for each article. I would like the menu item "News" to be active as the parent of each article node, but I would like to disable the dropdown menu (No need to have dozens of articles in a dropdown). I am using Superfish and have the dropdown enabled for all other menu items. Is there any way to disable it for a single menu item? Perhaps I need a different menu module?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks!

susanhouser

**EDIT**

Here is a screenshot to help illustrate:

http://screencast.com/t/3eyDuK0w

**EDIT02**

I ended up coming across a solution that fit my need (See answer below). Instead of setting News as the parent menu item for each article (I was doing this to generate the class "active-trail"), I used the plugin described in my answer. Thanks for all of the help!

Comment: Are you currently seeing content titles in your drop-down menu (Never seen that before)? If that is so, why would you do that in the first place?

Comment: Thanks @frazras. I think perhaps I have been unclear. I would like to make my article nodes children of the menu item "News" in order to have the class "active-trail" added to "News" whenever the user is viewing an article. I just do not want theses articles automatically added to a dropdown menu for "News". I have added a screenshot to illustrate. Hopefully that helps clarify!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving my problem by setting the url pattern for Articles to "news/[node:title]". I then used [Menu Trails](http://drupal.org/project/menu_trail_by_path) to highlight the News menu item based on the url path.

Now the "News" link will automatically be highlighted when viewing individual articles. Hopefully that helps someone else!

Answer (score 0):

You can configure "Menu Depth" option for that superfish block.

Also you can use css to hide the 2nd level dropdown UL

Comment: Thanks @gilzero. I have set the menu depth to 1 because I would like a dropdown menu for all the other links in that block. Is there a way to disable the dropdown for "News" alone? I have added a screenshot to help illustrate. Thanks again!

Comment: May be a new option, but Superfish block has now this option: 
<<Take "Expanded" option into effect. By enabling this option only parent menu items with Expanded option enabled will have their submenus appear.>>

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to do it with CSS. It's dirty, it's not drupal way, but it works.

Get the ID of the `<li>` element of News then put:

```
#id-of-element ul {
  display:none!important;
}
```

The !important bit **may** not work on IE6 though, unless your page is rendered in standards compliant mode.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189621/when-does-csss-important-declaration-not-work) on Stackoverflow.com, particularly the second answer by Graphain.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and reference! I would like to do it "the Drupal way", but I will keep this solution in mind. It may turn out to be the most practical fix. Thx again!